# Get a listing of portfolio items and categories

Tags: admin, mysql

On my website I maintain a list of links to cases we’ve worked at.
The cases themselves contain descriptions plus two small lists, showing who worked on the case and what other cases exist in the same category.
The original programmer of the website used two lines for this:

```
[widget widget_name="avia_portfoliobox" widget_class_name="newsbox" title="In deze case is de opdrachtgever ondersteund door:" count="2" cat="82" excerpt="display title and excerpt"]

[widget widget_name="avia_portfoliobox" widget_class_name="newsbox" title="De Cases in deze groep" count="100" cat="76" excerpt="display title and excerpt"]
```

So in the first line reference is made to category 82 (`cat="82"`), in the second line reference is made to 76 (`cat="76"`)
Category 82 is a client, Category 76 is a group of similar cases. The categories are numbered just as they where generated, so there is no other logic in them.

The website is maintained in four languages on four databases(NL, UK, IT, CN) and when switching languages you’re actually switching databases.
Obviously due to various reasons (e.g. sequence mistake in making new categories), those databases do not synchronize the Category numbering.
Eg. Client 82 in NL is 84 in UK.

**My questions:**

Is there an easier way then exporting Mysql to Excel to get a list of the categories with number and content?

Is there a way to change the numbers of categories (e.g. change the UK client from 84 to 82)?

Thanks